# How to avoid an explicit loop when pulling out a vector of a particular member from a vector of a class containing that member

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class

```
struct Foo {double x; double y;}
```

and `std::vector<Foo> xy;`

I also have a function to pull out the `x` members:

```
std::vector<double> bar(const std::vector<Foo>& xy);
```

which loops through each element of `xy`.

Is there a way of using the C++ standard library so I can avoid an explicit `for` loop?

Comment: [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: Probably something like `std::transform` will work, but what is the problem with having a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). E.g.

```
std::vector<double> bar(const std::vector<Foo>& xy) {
    std::vector<double> rt;
    rt.reserve(xy.size());
    std::transform(std::begin(xy), 
                   std::end(xy), 
                   std::back_inserter(rt), 
                   [](const Foo& f) { return f.x; });
    return rt;
}
```

For comparison here's the version using range-based for loop. As @463035818_is_not_a_number [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69160099/how-to-avoid-an-explicit-loop-when-pulling-out-a-vector-of-a-particular-member-f/69160149#comment122236041_69160149) it needs less typing.

```
std::vector<double> foo(const std::vector<Foo>& xy) {
    std::vector<double> rt;
    rt.reserve(xy.size());
    for (auto const & f : xy) rt.push_back(f.x);
    return rt;
}
```

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that since there are range based loops, the manually written loop is sometimes less to type and more readable. Also there is no `back_emplacer` afaik

Comment: Thank you very much. (I was attempting to use std::generate_n). Presumably you don't really need the reserve?

Comment: @P45Imminent `reserve` is highly recommend when the size is known in advance, it could avoid reallocation of `std::vector`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, for loop version added. BTW I'm not using `back_emplacer`?

Comment: its not needed here, but sometimes I find myself using an algorithm with a `back_inserter` when actually I'd rather use `emplace`. In a loop thats not an issue

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Fine, get what you mean.

Comment: I prefer `std::mem_fn(&Foo::x)` to a lambda when the algorithm doesn't `invoke` it's projection

Answer (score 3):

Using C++20's ranges offers a somewhat briefer alternative to `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<double> filtered;
filtered.reserve(xy.size());
std::ranges::copy(
  std::ranges::views::transform(xy, &Foo::x),
  std::back_inserter(filtered));
```

Or, as pointed out by @StoryTeller, as an alternative and even briefer approach to the init-empty-and-back-insert, use a view to directly intitialize the `filtered` vector (an approach that would allow it to be `const`):

```
auto view = xy | std::ranges::views::transform(&Foo::x);
std::vector<double> const filtered(view.begin(), view.end());
```

Comment: an even briefer alternative is `auto view = xy | std::ranges::views::transform(&Foo::x); return std::vector<double>(begin(view), end(view));`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah that's nice, thanks! Particularly replacing the lambda with the pointer to data member (which applies also to make my approach shorter).

Answer (score 1):

Well, behind the scenes there obviously has to be a loop somewhere. So it seems to me that the STL included `for_each` for this exact type of problem.

We can write the `Bar` function like so:

```
#include <algorithm>

auto Bar (const std::vector<Foo> & xy)
{
    std::vector<double> bar;
    bar.reserve(xy.size());
    auto extract_x = [&](const Foo & f){bar.push_back(f.x);};
    std::for_each(xy.begin(), xy.end(), extract_x);
    return bar;
}
```

Demos:

- [c++14](https://godbolt.org/z/P1f8EPvj5)
- [c++11](https://godbolt.org/z/zqz8zfMKa) (no return `auto`)

---

I think it's a good idea to prepare a few generic function wrappers of your own to avoid all those `begin`/`end`s. eg:

```
template <typename Containter, typename Functor>
void ForIndices (const Containter & c, Functor && f)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i)
        f(i);
}
```

Use like so:

```
auto Bar (const std::vector<Foo> & xy)
{
    std::vector<double> bar(xy.size());
    ForIndices(xy, [&](int i){bar[i] = xy[i].x;});
    return bar;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4qzr6Pxfo)

Comment: `std::for_each` is for the case when you already have iterators and only iterators (say you are implementing a generic algorithm yourself).  Even then, those cases when the code isn't actually contorted to fit are rare.

Comment: `std::for_each(it, it_end, func);` is both shorter (less noisy), named (a point in favor of preferring algorithms to raw loops), and probably more prone to optimizations than a raw loop. Standard library algorithms are typically written to in a way that complements compiler optimizations.